# navigationItem.titleView is taking space form the leftBarButtonItems in ios 11

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationitem, ios11, xcode9beta6

I am setting titleView using this method

```
func addConstrainstToSearchField(with size: CGSize? = nil) {
        var width : CGFloat = 0.0
        if let searchField = self.searchfield {
            var frame = searchField.frame
            if size != nil, let frameWidth = size?.width {
                width = frameWidth
            } else if let frameWidth = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.width {
                width = frameWidth
            }
            frame.size.width = (width - 145.0) * 0.90 // 136 is width of (left and right BarButtonItems) button
            searchField.frame = frame
            self.navigationItem.titleView = searchField
//            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
//                self.navigationItem.titleViewWithConstraint = searchField
//            })
        }
    }
```

and I am calling this method from viewdidload and viewWillTransiion

but it's not showing properly

screenshot [In landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wkc9u.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8S3Uh.png)

thanks in advance